# Multiple radio type with a update query

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input

I have 1 form where I show a couple of records from my DB. In each row I want 2 radio buttons with a On and Off button.

Now I want to update a column "a_active" in my DB. With a answer 1=On 0=off. I have for each row a unique (name) token.

I tried couple of ways with a for each loop. But every time he chanced non of the records or he changed only the last one.

If I do only a Print_R after submitting my form I got the right array back. [rowid]= 1 or 0.

```
<form type="POST">
<input type="text" value="<?=$get_token?>" name="token[]" hidden/>

<input type="radio" name="actie[<?php echo $row["user_id"];?>]" value="1"<? if ($active === "1"){echo "checked";}?>/>On

<input type="radio" name="actie[<?php echo $row["user_id"];?>]" value="0"<? if ($active === "0"){echo "checked";}?>/>Off

<button class="btn btn-info" name="submit" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

<?php

$id = $_POST['token'];
$code = $_POST['actie'];

foreach($_POST['actie'] as $count => $actie){

$query_core_user = "
UPDATE TableName
SET 
a_active='".$code[$count]."'
WHERE user_id= '".$id[$count]."'";

$resultcore_user = $conn->query($query_core_user) or die($conn->error);
}
?>
```

Comment: You can't `foreach` on radio buttons of the same name group. No idea why you'd want to use that.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I don't know a other way? do I need checkboxes than? I only want to update the column "a_active" with a 0 or 1 by all the records.

Comment: Just remove the foreach altogether and use the related POST array for it that you used while using `isset()` in a conditional `if` statement.

Comment: If anything though, the `foreach` should be used for the `name="token[]"` in your input set as hidden, but I'm not sure if that's the intention here. I don't think that that should even be an multidimensional array. Hard to say why you're using it. When using `[]`, it is expected to have more of the same, and resembles what checkboxes are used for doing stuff like this.